# Transformar uma animação scss para que se adeque ao angular animations

Tags: angular, css-animations

Olá, preciso de colocar no meu angular animations a seguinte animação scss:

```
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Minha trigger:

```
 trigger('fadeInUp', [
      state('true', style({
        opacity: '0',
        transform: 'translate3d(0,100%,0)'
      })),
      transition('false => true', animate('1s'))
    ])
```

Minha div alvo:

```
<div hidden [@fadeInUp]="menub2w" class="teste">

    <div class="col-12 alinhaSideNav">
        <span class="tipografianivel2">Mensagens</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 alinhaSideNav">
        <span class="tipografianivel2">Reclamações</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 alinhaSideNav">
        <span class="tipografianivel2">Anúncios</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Coloquei opacidade 0 nessa div, pra trocar no animation...

```
 .teste{
     opacity: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Cara na verdade esse CSS é simples, não parece SCSS... De qq forma, vc fez ou usou o @keyframe?

Comment: não, é só isso mesmo

Comment: Normalmente animações CSS são construídas dentro dos @keyframes ... Veja aqui https://tableless.com.br/css3-animation-keyframe/ e aqui tb https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar tb https://gist.github.com/mirisuzanne/1607696

Comment: minha dúvida mesmo é como colocar no angular rs